# Why does multiprocessing Queue.get() block after the queue is closed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker_main(q):
    while True:
        message = q.get()


q = Queue()
worker = Process(target=worker_main, args=(q,))
worker.start()
q.close()
worker.join()
```

I expect the call to `q.get` in `worker_main()` to throw an exception and exit after `q` is closed. Instead it hangs ever after the queue is closed in the main process.

My use case seems to be slightly different than the common examples which show `Queue.put` in the worker process and `Queue.get` in the main process.

In a main process I'm producing tasks that need to be distributed to a pool of worker processes via a queue. However when the tasks are complete I close the queue to indicate to the worker processes it's time to exit.

Perhaps I do not understand the documentation, but I think it's clear that future calls to `get` should raise an exception after `close`.

> `get([block[, timeout]])`
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args *`block`* is `True` (the default) and *`timeout`* is `None` (the default), block if necessary until an item is available. If `timeout` is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the `queue.Empty` exception if no item was available within that time. Otherwise (block is `False`), return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the `queue.Empty` exception (timeout is ignored in that case).
>
> Changed in version 3.8: **If the queue is closed, `ValueError` is raised instead of `OSError`.**

Comment: Hmmm... **future** calls... But `q.get()` can be called before the queue is closed. That sounds like a bug, but maybe you can workaround by using timeouts ?

Comment: The documentation also specifically says that `close` indicates the *current* process will not put any more items in the queue. `worker_main` is executed in a different process than the one that called `q.close()`.

Comment: @Vincent Fourmond I've tried changing `get` to `get(False, .1)`. It will throw `queue.Empty` to indicate there are no elements currently. However I would expect `ValueError` per the documentation, which the worker would use as a signal to stop waiting for new elements

Comment: @chepner I see, perhaps I was incorrectly assuming the other end would be closed as well. What would be the correct way to close the queue in other processes?

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard way to close, but I send a well-known sentinel (`None` is nice) per known reader of the queue. If some processes had terminated there will be too many None's in the queue... but it hasn't been a problem for me.

Comment: I don't think you do (or need to). There is a background thread that actually moves items from the queue to the pipe connecting the queue to another process. `close` just tells that thread it can exit once it has copied the last item, as you are promising not to add any more.

Comment: `close` is also documented as "usually unnecessary for most code". Its job isn't to pass messages to other processes, but to help the current process manage process-local resources.

Comment: ``Queue.close`` closes the *current process*' queue handle. It doesn't close the queue in other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `multiprocessing.Queue` represents a *handle* on a shared buffer. Notably, when processes are connected with a queue each process has its own copy of the handle.

Calling `.close()` only closes the current process' handle for reading and writing.

> #### [close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close)
>
> Indicate that no more data will be put on this queue by the *current process*. […]

---

In order to gracefully close a queue for all subscribers, send a "close message". This is usually a well-defined sentinel object such as `None`.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker_main(q):
    while (message := q.get()) is not None:
        print(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    q.put("Hello")
    worker = Process(target=worker_main, args=(q,))
    worker.start()
    q.put("World")
    q.put(None)  # close message
    q.close()
    worker.join()
```